# Flutter svg failed to load

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using `flutter_svg` package to load `.svg` image in my app.

Here is my code :

```
const String logo = "assets/vectors/raven_logo.svg";

SvgPicture.asset(
        logo,
        color: theme.primaryColorDark,
      ),
```

I have imported the assets in `pubspec.yml` file

```
assets:
    - assets/vectors/raven_logo.svg
```

Right now my assets folders has to folders in it : images and vectors and I have specified the exact path of the assets yet I am getting the error.

```
Unable to load asset: assets/vectors/raven_logo.svg
```

Comment: check how many spaces you have on next line from `assets` in pubspec.yaml file, here you posted 4, 2 is needed.

Comment: hey there check for these 3 things.... 
1- pubspec yaml spaces( spacing has to be accurate or it wont detect.

2- You dont have to specify images separately in the pubspec , you mention your root folder like this 
 assets:
    - images/

3- as per flutter doc u hav to mention as final and not const  -> final String assetName = 'assets/image.svg';

Comment: and? This is exactly what I am pointing to you. Check how many spaces you have there.

Comment: I only have two spaces in my .yml file. Here more spacing was added automatically due to formatting.

Comment: If everithing is set correctly, you need to make cold app restart to asset be visible. Stop your app and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop and restart the app after add or rename .svg files.
And everthing works well :)